# What VectorDrawableCompat is for?

Tags: android, android-support-library

I've read [this](https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88#.qkjye06v0) article, but still it doesn't make sense to me.

Since gradle build tools 1.5.0 we can use vector drawables in the app. For Lollipop and above vectors are used and for below os versions gradle generates PNG files and places them in the drawable_'density'_v4.
OK, that's clear.

Now we have also compatibility support for vector drawables, I have followed [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) instructions to support them in my app, but when it was done and everything seems to work, I could still find in the apk file generated PNG files.

**So, what's the difference and why PNG files are generated if support drawable should be used?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Gradle 2 you need to add:

```
android {  
   defaultConfig {  
      vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
   }  
}
```

to your build.gradle.

For gradle 1.5

```
android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     generatedDensities = []  
   }  

 aaptOptions {  
  additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
   }  
 }
```

Full details here: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html

Comment: I've already said that I have followed the instructions, so I had those entries in the gradle.

Comment: it worked fine for me so try again. you must have missed something

Comment: Are you sure you didn't have PNG files generated in the app? Also if I have library modules, do they also need those gradle entries?

Comment: Can I do this in an Eclipse Android project to which Gradle support has been added through the Gradle Buildship plugin?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between a)PNG generation solution Vs. b)VectorDrawableCompat is :

1) APK size. For a), you better use multi-apk such that one APK for >=21, one for <21. Such that, the APK size for >=21 can be reduced.
For b), the APK size should be reduced for the whole APK regardless of the min API level.

2) Functionality Limitation. For a) There is some rarely-used attributes inside Vectordrawable is not support. For b) Although all attributes are supported, it requires some code change, like from anrdoid:src to app:srcCompat.

3) Reference: For a), you can refer to VectorDrawable (or generated PNG) anywhere in the Java / XML, without knowing it is Vector or not. But for b) you have to use app:srcCompat to refer to VectorDrawableCompat, or use within DrawableContainer.

In short, if you target for the best APK size for all OS version and don't mind changing the code a bit, use VectorDrawableCompat. Otherwise, the PNG generation + separate APK will be good enough for you.